# MyPy Type Check variable with class type assigned None

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am attempting to type check a large python code base. One of the cases is the type checking of a variable whose variable type is a class but assigned as None during initialization. I have added a couple other cases where MyPy would pass the code base without any complaints

```
from typing import Union, Optional

class TestClass(object):

   def __init__(this, pValue:float = 0.0):
      # This line will fail with 'Incompatible types in assignment (expression 
      # has type "None", variable has type "TestClass")'
      this._test_class:TestClass = None
      this._test_a:Optional[TestClass] = None
      
   def doSomething(this) -> None:
      if not this._test_class == None:
         # Use of the Optional typing will cause this line tobytes
         # fail with 'Item "None" of "Optional[TestClass]" has 
         # not attribute "doCalculate"'
         new_val:float = this._test_a.doCalculate()
      
   def doCalculate(this) -> float:
      return 0.0
      
# Code below all pass
class ClassA(object):
   def __init__(this):
      this._test_class:ClassA = None
      pass
      
   def doSomething(this) -> None:
      if not this._test_class == None:
         new_val:float = this._test_class.doCalculate()
      
   def doCalculate(this) -> float:
      return 0.0
      
class ClassB(object):
   def __init__(this, pValue = 0.0):
      this._test_class:ClassB = None
      pass
   
   def doSomething(this) -> None:
      if not this._test_class == None:
         new_val:float = this._test_class.doCalculate()
      
   def doCalculate(this) -> float:
      return 0.0
```

The version of MyPy I am utilizing is 0.971 (compiled: yes)

Why, during type checking, MyPy will throw an error on ClassType that passes a value with defined type but will pass the case in ClassB?

The solution would be to remove the float typing from `TestClass.__init__` but that defeats the purpose of documenting types.

Comment: `Optional[ClassType]` is supposed to be the solution. This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. Your `mypy` version probably is necessary too

Comment: Barmar, that is the recommendation from the MyPy documentation. ```Optional[TestClass]``` (was originally ClassType) will generate a different error somewhere else within the class. I have improved the example to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Further review, was able to uncover the solution. Per Barmar, the Optional type should allow for both None and object type. Further in the example, there is a statement for checking against None

```
      if not this._test_class == None:
         new_val:float = this._test_a.doCalculate()
```

Because I used the equality operators (== or !=), this does something totally different than using 'is'

to make the entire TestClass pass MyPy with strictly checked enabled, the code is modified as such

```
from typing import Optional

class TestClass(object):

   def __init__(this, pValue:float = 0.0):
      this._test_class:Optional[TestClass] = None
      this._test_a:Optional[TestClass] = None
      
   def doSomething(this) -> None:
      if not this._test_a is None:
         new_val:float = this._test_a.doCalculate()
      if not this._test_class is None:
         new_val = this._test_class.doCalculate()
      
   def doCalculate(this) -> float:
      return 0.0
```

Real Python has a good description of ==, != and is operators. (See [https://realpython.com/courses/python-is-identity-vs-equality/#:~:text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20compares%20the,the%20same%20object%20in%20memory.](https://realpython.com/courses/python-is-identity-vs-equality/#:%7E:text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20compares%20the,the%20same%20object%20in%20memory.))